# Children position of ofNode based class?

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm creating objects, instances of `ofNode`, let call them cards. Every card has it's own properties, like buttons, text and images, which are drawn in card `.draw()` function.

If I change card location "children" objects aren't moving along. Is there any way to bind their position to their card object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setParent` method:

```
ofNode parent;
ofNode child;
child.setParent(parent);

parent.setGlobalPosition(10, 20, 30);
child.setPosition(100, 200, 300);

ofVec3f pos = child.getGlobalPosition(); // pos == (110, 220, 330)
```

Note that `setPosition` is local, which is related to its parent position, while `setGlobalPosition` is global.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are meaning move in a graphical manner. This is very implementation dependent. I don' know open frameworks, but to take Qt as example here you would combine all graphical elements as childs of the main structure, the card. E.g. let card inherit from some super-object (a frame or sth. alike) and include all children into the card. In Qt this is done by parent child relationships.

Comment: ofNode, my base class, is theoretically base 3d object in openFrameworks - probably in Qt every display object inherit realtivly parent position, but I don't know how to do this in openFamerworks